# Batch to filter the matching lines in file to output

Tags: batch-file

Hlelo,
Script that is not working is as below,

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo.
echo.
echo.
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (find.txt) do (
   set "in=%%a"
   for %%v in (INT CHAR) do if "!in:*%%v=%%v!" neq "!in!" set "out=!in:*%%v=%%v!"
   echo !out!
)) > D:\test\TGT.txt
```

Every line ends with string ex: `abc` or `abc_01` / `DEF` or `DEF_02` etc

Please advise on a script which will capture and print only lines staring with `INT` or `CHAR` and last string doesn't have `_01` or `_02` at the end. Here `_` (underscore) is the key to identify and ignore the line.

`source.txt`

```
INT SDFF 9784 abc
INT SDFF 098 abc_01
INT SDFF 9784 abc_02
ABC INT SDFF 098 abc_03
CHAR SDFF 9784 xyz
CHAR SDFF 098 XYZ_02
INT jkdf 981 DEF
```

`out.txt` (expected result)

```
INT SDFF 9784 abc
CHAR SDFF 9784 xyz
INT jkdf 981 DEF
```

Comment: You should be able to pipe the output of one `FINDSTR` command to another `FINDSTR` command to get your desired result but you may want to use a different scripting language that has more powerful Regular Expression Capability.

Comment: `<source.txt >out.txt find /v "_"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution for this line filtering task:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /R "CHAR\> INT\>" "source.txt" | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /V "_[0123456789][0123456789]*$" >"out.txt"
```

The first **FINDSTR** searches with a case-sensitive **r**egular expression in file `source.txt` for lines **b**eginning with either the word `CHAR` or the word `INT`. A line beginning for example with `CHARACTER` or `INT32` is ignored by first **FINDSTR**.

**Note:** A space in a search string enclosed in `"` without `/C:` left to the search string is interpreted as logical **OR**.

The found lines are redirected with `|` as input for the second **FINDSTR**.

The second **FINDSTR** searches with a case-sensitive **r**egular expression for lines ending with an underscore and one or more digits and outputs the in**v**erted result which means all lines **NOT** ending with an underscore and one or more digits.

**Note:** It is also possible to use `[0-9]` instead of `[0123456789]`, but `[0-9]` includes also the three characters `¹²³`.

The output of second **FINDSTR** is redirected with `>` to the file `out.txt`.

Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), run `findstr /?` and read the output help for even more details on the used options and regular expressions.

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of the redirection operators `|` and `>`.